# Trouble solving a quadratic equality in x which has a single unknown

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

I have a relatively straightforward inequality to solve but I am getting stuck because I don't know what to do with the unknown...

$$x^2 + b^2 > 0, b > 0$$

The aim is to solve the inequality for all values of x. I can't factorise the expression so I wasn't able to draw a sketch of intercepts to help me.

Some pointers in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are adding two squares they are always positive or equal to zero. As $b>0$ the inequality is strictly positive for all $x \in R$.

Comment: what would happen if I had $x^2 + b^2 < 0$?

Comment: Then this inequality would not be valid. As the sum of two squares, with one of them beeing greater than zero is never negative.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. What if the two terms were swapped in order? Would that change the inequality at all? For example $b^2-x^2<0$?

Comment: Now you would rewirte $b^2-x^2=(b-x)(b+x)<0$. This inequality is true if the sign of $(b-x)$ and $(b+x)$ are opposite. Hence $b-x>0$ and $b+x<0$ or $b-x<0$ and $b+x>0$. You could also plot $f(x)=b^2-x^2$ to see that this is a parabola which is open down. There are two zeros at $x_{1/2}=\pm b$. The function is negative for all values $x<-b$ and $x>b$.

Comment: Since $b^2$ would always be positive, couldn't you just simply say that for $b^2-x^2 < 0$, then $x > b$ ?

Comment: You could do that, but you would miss one part of you solution. If you want to do it this way you will have to write $|x|>b$.

Comment: So the fact that the problem states that b is a positive constant is basically irrelevant in this case?